# For loop to send emails with VBA: Only first email sends

Tags: vba, email, for-loop

Sorry if this is close to a duplicate question or not formatted correctly, this is a first-time for me.

In VBA, I am trying to loop through my spreadsheet and send emails when a cell value is equal to 1. This code works to send the first email(or occurence of 1 in the worksheet), but does not execute to send a second or any other emails.

I have looped through using F8, and it picks up the "With Outmail" function anytime there is a 1, but it just doesn't send the email after the first occurrence.

Thank you in advance.

```
Sub Send_Email_Function()
'This cycles through a worksheet and sends email reminders when due dates 
have not been met.

'Establish Variables and variable types
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim RecEmail As String
Dim AgmtNum As String
Dim AgmtProduct As String
Dim AgmtDate As String
Dim i As Integer

'Create mail objects
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

'Start "i" for looping
For i = 26 To 29

'Assign variables to table and
RecipientEmail = Sheet1.Cells(1, 3).Value
AgmtNum = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value
AgmtProduct = Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Value
AgmtDate = Sheet1.Cells(i, 5).Value

On Error Resume Next

'Loop through each cell in column 14 to check if value is 1 or 0, send email if 1

If Sheet1.Cells(i, 14).Value = 1 Then

'Send mail to recipient with the following information
With OutMail
'.To = ""
'.CC = ""
.BCC = RecipientEmail
.Subject = AgmtNum + " " + "Deliverable Auto-Reminder"
.Body = "Insert body here"
'.Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
.Send   'or use .Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0
End If

'Increment i for looping, wait at least 10 seconds before sending next email
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
Next i

'Clean up Outmail and OutApp
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Take out your `On Error Resume Next` and step thru it slowly and watch what happens.

Comment: Hi @braX , I tried this but the results didn't seem to change nor did I have anything out of the ordinary happen.

Answer (score 3):

Put `Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)` inside the `loop`.

Just the first e-mail is being sent because when you try to send the second one you are actually overwriting the first one, you are editing the same `OutMail` object. It doesn't get sent because it has been already in the first iteration.

```
For i = 26 To 29
    .
    .
    .
    If Sheet1.Cells(i, 14).Value = 1 Then
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0) 'Create a new mail item for every mail that has to be sent
```

The correction above should fix it

Comment: It won't let me upvote without having a greater reputation, but I wanted to comment that @Danilo Favato 's solution solved this issue. Thank you Danilo and I apologize if this is not the appropriate place to thank someone, please provide guidance for how to do this without reputation.

Comment: You can mark my post as the answer, so everyone will know.